# Convert PHP string to JSON array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

**Problem:**

Converting a PHP string to a JSON array.

I have a string in PHP that looks like this:

```
intelligence skin weight volume
```

**Desired output:**

Is there a way in PHP where I can convert it so it looks like this instead:

```
["skin", "intelligence", "weight", "volume"]
```

I looked at json_encode() but that only put double quotes around the keywords.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create JSON array, you have to first explode your input string into an array.

Try with:

```
$input  = 'intelligence skin weight volume';
$output = json_encode(explode(' ', $input));
```

Answer (score 2):

first explode the string based on space. then u get an array containing individual words.then json_encode the array

```
$string="intelligence skin weight volume";
$array=explode(' ',$string);
$json=json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

This function would expect array and will convert array into json. Then use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to revert json to an array

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="intelligence skin weight volume";
$arr=explode(' ',$str);
$json=json_encode($arr);
```

explode() used to split a string by a delimiter(in this senarion it is " ") Now you can encode the returend array as json.

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode

```
$jsonVal = json_encode(explode(' ', "intelligence skin weight volume"));
```